# How to create a hash table in ATS?

Tags: ats

Could someone show me an example that makes typical use of a hash table? I want to build such a table to test whether a given string represents a legal word in a English dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [myhashtblref.hats](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS-Postiats/libats/ML/HATS/myhashtblref.hats) interface to quickly build your own hash table types. See [this chapter](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS2TUTORIAL/HTML/c942.html) of the ATS2 tutorial for a motivational example.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile to JavaScript, you can readily create a hash table in the following manner:

```
//
extern
fun
theWords_map_search(key: string): bool = "mac#"
//

%{^
//
var
theWords_map = {};
//
function
theWords_map_add(key)
  { theWords_map[key] = 0; return; }
//
function
theWords_map_search(key)
  { return theWords_map.hasOwnProperty(key); }
//
%} // end of [val]
```